# Treemap alternative that will show long labels

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, treemap

Is there a way to text wrap the labels on powerbi treemap or an alternative that wont take so much space? As you can see in the image below some labels are cropped and I would like to have the full labels showing in the visual instead. I tried a bar chart but it's a little to big due to the amount to categories.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA2CD.png)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there really isn't a workaround that's all that useful.
One of the ways I've seen is to just make the treemap as big as possible and make the detail font smaller. Which is a garbage solution IMO.

why Microsoft hasn't implemented Wordwrap for the treemap is absolutely beyond me...

My best suggestion is to add a filter limiting the number of squares there if the item is less than... say 80.
[Filter Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSy7B.png)